# Compute a new set of columns based on two different sets of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compute a new set of columns based on two sets of columns in pandas.   Here is sample code I am using.  It produces ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='M')
dft = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4),index=dates, columns=['var_A1', 
    'var_A2', 'var_B1', 'var_B2'])
list_A=['var_A1', 'var_A2']
list_B=['var_B1', 'var_B2']
list_C=['var_C1', 'var_C2']
dft[list_C]=dft[list_A]/dft[list_B]
```

Comment: Please state your desired output, I believe it is unclear.

Comment: I was trying to use broadcasting, but it does not seem to work with two different sets of columns.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Here is what I want: I would like var_C1=var_A1/var_B1 and similarly var_C2=Var_A2/var_B2.  I am using only two variables in each set just as an example.  In the real dataset I have close to 100 columns in each set and if I could specify just two sets/groups of columns and use them in a broadcasting fashion to create a new third set of columns, it would help me be more efficient.

Comment: That kind of information needs to be in your question, use the edit button to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `.values` , since pandas will check index and columns value when do the dataframe divide , then using `DataFrame` constructor re-format the result and `concat` back

```
C=pd.DataFrame(data=dft[list_A].values/dft[list_B].values,columns=list_C,index=dft.index) 

pd.concat([dft,C],axis=1)
Out[69]: 
              var_A1    var_A2     ...          var_C1      var_C2
2000-01-31  0.099688 -0.299652     ...       -0.680396   -0.184230
2000-02-29 -0.632817  0.448125     ...        7.323079   -0.229743
2000-03-31 -1.109919  0.532045     ...        7.358100    0.471776
2000-04-30 -0.658940 -1.999924     ...        1.116363    6.230502
2000-05-31 -0.483534 -0.530186     ...        0.422526    2.010115
2000-06-30  0.578555 -1.122150     ...        1.755439   -1.709229
2000-07-31  0.749859  0.059442     ...       -0.670673   -0.042344
2000-08-31  0.273163 -0.445727     ...       -0.230529   -0.635203
2000-09-30 -0.418762 -1.870431     ...       -1.072958   -2.763591
2000-10-31 -1.280142 -0.237272     ...       -0.820698    1.362289
2000-11-30  0.237335 -0.282515     ...       -3.832564   -0.919483
```

Comment: @Nora if this work for you would you like upvote and accept ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked well.  A related question: what if I were to create a new set of columns and multiplied or divided it by 1 column instead of the set, would I still need to use .values?  I just tried below code and it did not work, it produced error.  list_D=['var_D1', 'var_D2']
D=pd.DataFrame(data=dft[list_C].values/dft['var_A1'].values,columns=list_D,index=dft.index) 
dft=pd.concat([dft,D],axis=1)list_D=['var_D1', 'var_D2']

Comment: @Nora  in that case you can using df.div(df.col,axis=0)